# Dynamicaly reload remotes with ModuleFederationPlugin

Tags: vue.js, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I use micro frontend using promise-base dynamic remotes with webpack ModuleFederationPlugin.

My code is slightly more complexe than what is described here : https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#promise-based-dynamic-remotes, but the general idea is the same.

My problem is : I would like to dynamicaly (at runtime, using my host Vue.js app) reload theses remotes, for 2 reasons:

1. Micro frontend was not enabled first, and the user enable the functionality, so I want to load the corresponding remote
2. I want to make sure the remote is still available (not only in my browser cache) at some point

I see nowhere in the official documentation on how to update/reload (adding a ?v=Date.now() to make sure the cache is bust) the remotes at runtime. Reloading the page does the trick, but I am obviously trying to avoid that.

Thanks